# setInterval problems with a countdown timer using Draftbit

Tags: javascript, countdown, lowcode

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PpPBY.png)I have this set up to start a countdown timer...

```
const initialCountdown = 10; // Initial countdown value (change as needed)
let countdown = initialCountdown;

const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
  if (countdown > 0) {
    countdown--;
    setSeconds(countdown);
  } else {`your text`
    resetInterval(intervalId);
    countdown = initialCountdown;
    setSeconds(countdown);
  }
}, 1000);

function resetInterval(intervalId) {
  clearInterval(intervalId);
  // Perform any other reset operations here if needed
}
```

This starts the timer and resets it at 0

I need to stop it glitching when the start button is pressed twice and I need to add a stop/resume function to another button. I use draftbit which is a lowcode app app builder which allows custom code. i use an on press action for the button to start the timer (see attached). Ne to javaScript as you can probably tell ... Please help

I have tried several versions of the code and everything i have tried that is not the above totally breaks the timer

Comment: To add an image, click [edit] then the icon that looks like a mountain with a moon

Answer (score 0):

Just test if it is running

```js
const initialCountdown = 10; // Initial countdown value (change as needed)
let countdown = initialCountdown;
let intervalId;

function onPressHandler() {
  if (intervalId) return;
  let intervalId = setInterval(() => {
    if (countdown > 0) {
      countdown--;
      setSeconds(countdown);
    } else {
      resetInterval(intervalId);
      countdown = initialCountdown;
      setSeconds(countdown);
    }
  }, 1000);
}

function resetInterval(intervalId) {
  clearInterval(intervalId);
  // Perform any other reset operations here if needed
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help! this didn't run unfortunately

Comment: In what way? Error message? I can only guess since you do not have a proper JS implementation

Comment: when i press the on press trigger which is connected to the code you gave me ... the countdown doesn't start... again thanks for your help

Comment: Can you show how you assign the handler? I called it onPressHandler expecting you to know how to use it

Comment: yes .. sorry iim very new to this ... this being the action when the trigger/button is pressed?

Comment: `I use an on press action for the button to start the timer`

Comment: Perhaps you just need to add `onPressHandler()`  in the action

Comment: could you tell me how to do that?

Comment: No. I have no knowledge of draftbit. Perhaps you show how you add YOUR code to draftbit

Comment: is there a way to add an image here